# How to ignore WebService error in JBoss EAP 6?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws, jax-rpc

I have to make a compatible .ear for WebSphere 6.1 (which is only JAX-RPC/Java1.5) and JBoss EAP 6 (JAX-WS/Java7). There is a webservice in WebSphere 6.1 that works with JAX-RPC and i want to create the exact same webservice in JBoss using JAX-WS. But my problem is that once JBoss encountered a error in the JAX-RPC service it stops from deploying the rest of the application. Is there a way to make JBoss ignore the JAX-RPC service and only initialize JAX-WS ? Or is it possible to completely deactivate JAX-RPC with deployment.xml?

Regards

Edit :

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."YYY.ear"."waYYY.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."YYY.ear"."waYYY.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: N'a pas pu traiter la phase INSTALL de subdeployment "waYYY.war" of deployment "YYY.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: JBWS025146: Cannot obtain java type mapping for: {urn:YYYEventWS/types}doConsume
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxrpc.JAXRPCMetaDataBuilder.processDocElement(JAXRPCMetaDataBuilder.java:583)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxrpc.JAXRPCMetaDataBuilder.buildParameterMetaDataDoc(JAXRPCMetaDataBuilder.java:840)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxrpc.JAXRPCMetaDataBuilder.setupOperationsFromWSDL(JAXRPCMetaDataBuilder.java:202)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxrpc.JAXRPCServerMetaDataBuilder.buildMetaData(JAXRPCServerMetaDataBuilder.java:197)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.start(UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Could you please paste the error and stack trace that you see when you deploy the application in JBoss?

Comment: are you able to resolve the issue?